# MAMP PRO Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE in my.cnf

Tags: mysql, mamp, mamp-pro, my.cnf

I'm trying to disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE in MAMP PRO mysql.
I've changed my.cnf in mysql templates, restart mysql server but unfortunately it's still the same.
So, what i'm doing wrong? How to fix?
[image: Screenshot of my.cnf and mysql state]

Answer (score 18):

Just faced this issue today. I'll leave an answer for the record. It's based in [this article](http://icreatestuff.co.uk/blog/setting-up-mysql-5-7-on-mamp-pro-v4-4).

On MAMP PRO go to File > Edit Template > MySQL.

In the editor, find [mysqld] line. Beneath that line add the following:

```
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

*(applied to this particular question)*

```
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

*(this is what I actually used)*

[where to place the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCf70.png)

Cheers and keep coding.

Comment: I needed quotes around the string of sql modes

Answer (score 2):

You're using double quotes in your example. Use single quotes

```
sql_mode = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of 6.4 (and probably others), do the following:

Edit > Open Template > MySQL -> Version (x)

Then, add the following:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=""
```

[image]